# 'Of' and 'For' - A car of $30,000 vs A car for $30,000

Tags: difference

I'm not so sure but I think *'a car of $30,000'* simply means that the car is worth of $30,000; and *'a car for $30,000'* means that somebody **exchange** $30,000 for a car.

What is the difference in meaning between the phrase using 'of' and the other with 'for' do you think?

---

Added information:

'A car of $30,000' is the phrase I made up.  I'm learning about the preposition 'of' and pick up one of its usage **'used with measurements and expressions of time, age, etc.'**. There are some examples for this case, like **'2 kilos of potatoes, an increase of 2%, a girl of 12'**. With that I think maybe the phrase **'a car of $30,000'** matches  the concept.

I got feedbacks from somes ell users, all of them are not with me about 'a car of $30,000'. The thing that keeps bother me is that preposition 'of' can be used to show possession, **why can it not be applied in this case, 'a car of $30,000'?**

Comment: In the first case, we would not say "a car of $30,000" but "a $30,000 car" to indicate its price tag.

Comment: It is also unsual to "exchange $30,000 for a car". We say "buy a car for $30,000."

Comment: I can't think of a case where 'a car of $30,000' would be used by a native speaker, so the question is rather moot.

Comment: I think this is a fair question, but could you tells us a bit more about "car of $30,000". Where did you find this, or how did you come up with it? That might help users better understand your problem.

Comment: Hi @Em. , I added some information about the problem I got in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A car “of $30,000” suggests that somehow the car was built using thirty thousand dollar bills. I suppose using paper mâché? You would say, fairly naturally, “a car of steel and rubber”:

> When a man of flesh and bone meets a car of steel and rubber, at any speed, it will end in tears.

If there were a Great Depression, Jenő Rejtő's [14-carat Roadster](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9977482-the-14-carat-roadster) might conceivably be a **car of $30,000 in gold**. But that would still be a car of gold, worth $30,000.